# Trigger an email if Apache server or DB server stopped

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

Is there any way to know the Apache/Nginx server has stopped? 
Nginx stopped working 2 days ago and my website was down for these days, and I didn't know about it.

Please let me know if there is any way to get an email notification if my website is down or any server stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a provider like [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) that provides HTTP server checks and uptime alerts for your website.

You can also run your own monitoring and alerting infrastructure using e.g. [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io) but that can be a lot of overhead for just one simple website.